# Select2 appending duplicate selected items

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I've got the following code for populating a dropdown with a list of children returned from the /get_children endpoint:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.child-select').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select a child',
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/get_children',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    search: params.term // Pass the search query to the server
                };
            },
            processResults: function(data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        templateResult: function(child) {
            return $('<span>').text(child.name).attr('title', child.grade);
        }
    }).on('select2:select', function(e) {
        var selectedChild = e.params.data;
        var option = new Option(selectedChild.name, selectedChild.id, true, true);
        $('.child-select').append(option).trigger('change');
});
```

However each time I select a child from the dropdown, two items are added to the selected items: a blank one and one with the child's name:

[image: screenshot]

Why is this happening and how do I ensure it just adds the one item with the child's name?

Comment: Why are you trying to add elements in `on('select2:select'...` function? Elements are already being added with select2 by default.

Comment: @Batu.Khan I wasn't aware of that! I've removed the ```on('select2:select'...``` code. It was still though showing a blank selected element, so I've added this line to fix it: ```templateSelection: function(child) {return child.name}``` and that seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Batu.Khan is there a way to disable the default adding of elements? I now want to use ```on('select2:select'...``` to add the selected name to another element on the page, and don't want anything selected to display in the dropdown itself.